# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS(Jammy Jellyfish) Installing Wifi Driver

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows. I was realizing that WiFi speed is slow.
I tried to install the WiFi driver (I use tplinkwn823n pc) from the official website(Linux).
The guide says to use, in step `3. Type “sudo make” to compile the driver file. 4. Type “sudo make install” to install the driver file.`
following the instruction from the installation guide this error

```
c1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /home/rappa/Downloads/TL-WN823N_US_V3_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1881: /home/rappa/Downloads/TL-WN823N_US_V3_160315_Linux/Driver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-47-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1696: modules] Error 2
```

[error show in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OYBu.png)

Comment: i  can't show full log since it said spam, anybody know? i just wan install wifi driver

Comment: The download page says: "Operating System: Linux (kernel 2.6.24 ~ <4.9.60)" Ubuntu 22.04 uses a much more recent kernel, 5.15.0-xx. In other words, the official driver is too old. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: [here is the result of terminal command: lsusb][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/awc8o.png

Comment: Your device 2357:0109 TP-Link TL WN823N RTL8192EU is covered by the driver rtl8xxxu that’s included in recent Ubuntu versions. May we see: `sudo modprobe rtl8xxxu && sudo dmesg | grep 8xxx`

Comment: should i restart after doing the command?

Comment: You should post the results of the command so that we may review them.

Comment: here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n6pG.png

Comment: the driver is already installed but the wifi is 2 bar but the router is on my side

Comment: Let's  also see: `sudo dmesg | grep wlx` and also: `nmcli device wifi list'

Comment: See also: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/327339).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the RTL8192EU(TP-LINK WN823N)

1. Installing headers:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
   ```
2. Clone Repository:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
   cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
   ```
3. Adding Driver to DMKS:

   ```
   sudo dkms add .
   ```
4. Build and install driver:

   ```
   sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
   ```
5. Distributions based on Ubuntu have RTL8XXXU Driver present running in kernelspace. Since We install rtl8192eu, we should blacklist the RTL8XXXU by running this command:

   ```
   echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf
   ```
6. Forcing the RTL8192EU to run in boot:

   ```
   echo -e "8192eu\n\nloop" | sudo tee /etc/modules
   ```
7. Update change to GRUB/BIOS & inittramfs:

   ```
   sudo update-grub; sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

   Then reboot:

   ```
   systemctl reboot -i
   ```

Related issue: [How do I get a TP-Link TL-WN823N V3 wireless adapter working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211157/how-do-i-get-a-tp-link-tl-wn823n-v3-wireless-adapter-working)

Sumarize: if you using latest ubuntu 20.04 LTS Very Recommended to install via git dmks, my ubuntu version was 22.04 LTS Latest Trying To Compile with the TL823N showing error(ubuntu 22.04 kernel isn't support, since it only support 5.15.0-xx). try to install from gitclone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver (latest),after adding the to dmks, it won't readable because there is a RTL8XXX driver, by blacklisting(or disable) the driver the RTL8192EU Swith be primary driver because rtl8xxx was disable.