# Does the TP-Link TL-WN823N USB WiFi adapter work in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: wireless, adapter

I need to buy a usb wifi adapter for Ubuntu 20.Tp link TL-WN823N is available in my area. Is it compatible with Ubuntu 20?

Comment: Search this site for **TL-WN823N**. You will see many posts. If you buy this adapter. Try it first. If it is not recognized, you may have to compile the drive from source code following the instructions in [one of the Q&A here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1430148/ubuntu-22-04-1-ltsjammy-jellyfish-installing-wifi-driver/1431743#1431743).